# Paying own taxes as an Independent contractor in Scotland

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, tax-deductions, contracts, payment

I will be working as an independent short term contractor for the first time.

The company I signed a contract with is a private language school and I will be tutoring one of their student , giving one to one private lessons.

It will be up to 20 hrs a week and 200 hrs in total.Which is about 2.5 months or so.

I will receive the payment monthly and also must submit invoices monthly.

On the contract it states that Iam an independent contractor, and not an employee of

Language Trainers, and i am responsible for my own income taxes, and this must be stated this clearly on every invoice.

I would really appreciate if you someone can help me regarding the steps I should follow in Scotland and whether i should get these sorted through internet way before I get paid.

Thank you in advance

Nysa

Comment: Unless you have your own company I guess you are considered self-employed. You should check https://www.gov.uk/working-for-yourself/overview and https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/self-employed-or-looking-for-work/self-employment-checklist/ before starting.

Comment: That said I'm not sure whether your question is an expat issue (unless you have issues with getting a work visa), you might find better help on other sites, like http://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just to be clear the 'Language Trainer' company is Scottish and will be paying you in Scotland (rather than being global and just contracting to Scotland on this occasion). And are you a UK citizen, if not how long have you been resident in Scotland?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, really useful tips indeed! I don't have my own company and I am not a UK citizen either. I have been living here since January 2015 and have a working permit. Do you think it would be wise to go through an umbrella company if the Language Trainer company have no problem with it. Thank you!

Comment: Where you are a citizen also makes a difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires a tax attorney (and perhaps an Immigration attorney).